# .Net Core Angular 4 - Duplicate app component on bundle rebuilding

Tags: angular, webpack, .net-core, angular-animations

My project is using the Visual Studio .Net-Core AngularJS Template (i.e with the `app.module.shared.ts`,`app.module.browser.ts`,`app.module.server.ts` files)

I was having a strange issue whereby whenever I made changes a new `<app>` element was being added to my DOM, and the old `<app>` element wasn't being removed.
If I refreshed the page it all went back to normal.

Comment: Is this supposed to be tagged `Angular` and not `AngularJS` (looking at your answer).

Comment: yeah it was, thanks. Updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much searching it turned out it was due to having this in my `app.module.browser.ts` file

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppModuleShared
],
```

Once I remove the BrowserAnimationsModule line, the duplication issue stopped.

So the imports section becomes:

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppModuleShared
],
```

I have no idea if this is a webpack issue, an angular issue, or an issue with the MS way of having app.module split into multiple files... But that's what is causing it if you run into this issue!

It's easy to duplicate for those interested, just start a new template project and add that line.

Update: Adding `BrowserAnimationsModule` import to the `app.module.shared.ts` file also had the same issue, as does `NoopAnimationsModule`

Update 2:
I just found this GIT issue with a proper workaround to remove the old `<app>`
https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/1165

Answer (score 0):

The fix for me was to update the `boot.browser.ts` file to include `oldRootElem!.remove();`:

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'zone.js';
import 'bootstrap';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.browser.module';

if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept();
    module.hot.dispose(() => {
        // Before restarting the app, we create a new root element and dispose the old one
        const oldRootElem = document.querySelector('app');
        const newRootElem = document.createElement('app');
        oldRootElem!.parentNode!.insertBefore(newRootElem, oldRootElem);
        oldRootElem!.remove();
        modulePromise.then(appModule => appModule.destroy());
    });
} else {
    enableProdMode();
}

// Note: @ng-tools/webpack looks for the following expression when performing production
// builds. Don't change how this line looks, otherwise you may break tree-shaking.
const modulePromise = platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

This way you can still include the `BrowserAnimationsModule` (See answer from *@James*).